# CQ5 DAM history information

Tags: aem

How do I check history of a DAM asset (Ex: pdf)?
I would like to find information such as its activation and deactivation history.

Comment: I am not sure if you can view it in some console. But you can check it in CRXDE at the following location `/var/audit/com.day.cq.replication/content/dam/<<path to your asset>>`

Comment: Agreed ! I think "/var/audit/com.day.cq.replication/content/dam" is his best bet !

Comment: Yes,I can see history there ! Thank you Very much for your quick response!!

Answer (score 0):

All the audit information can be found under `/var/audit` in CRXDE.

For replication history `/var/audit/com.day.cq.replication/` followed by the page / asset path would provide you with the required information.

For e.g., `cq:AuditEvent` nodes with `cq:category` as `com/day/cq/replication` under `/var/audit/com.day.cq.replication/content/dam/geometrixx/banners/dsc.jpg` would provide you information about the replication history for that particular asset in case it is available.